# SharePoint Online - External Sharing failed: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: item-level-permissions, external-users, sharepoint-permissions, external-sharing

#### The Goal

Share **one specific folder** in a SharePoint site with an external user (outside of tenant organization) and **include Edit permissions** without the user needing a Microsoft account.

#### My Environment

- SharePoint Online
- Admin Center > Policies > External Sharing > Most Permissive/Anyone ([See a screenshot here](https://prnt.sc/U9_Xeu7CTfjP))
- Admin Center > Site > External Sharing > Anyone ([See a screenshot here](https://prnt.sc/POPAvhhKNtfI))
- I do have custom code running: tenant wide extensions and web parts.

#### Expected and normal behavior

Microsoft confirmed (via my personal ticket) that it is possible to share just one folder to an external user.
I also tested it on another tenant and the external sharing was successful.
**Therefore, I know it's something to do with my specific tenant.**

#### The Issue

When I share the folder via "Copy Link" or "Share", after the external user enters the verification code, they can open the folder and **it appears just briefly (1/2 seconds)**, but then the page gets redirected to my organizations' login screen.

When I share the folder via "Manage Access" > "Advanced" > "Grant Permissions":
[image]

It won't even let me share it. I get an error within the browser:
[image]

```
Sharing failed: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
```

The issue occurs on all classic and modern Team and Communication sites.

##### **However, I am able to get it working on one specific classic Team site.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a custom-built tenant-wide SharePoint extension installed and active which was doing a "behind-the-scenes" user authentication (I think through `aadHttpClientFactory`) that caused any external user to hit a sign-in wall.